# Java flatten json documents

Tags: java, json, flatten, spagobi

I am a novice in Java and I am looking for a way to flatten json documents.

I have tried Object mapper but without success and I have  also tried to do with json node but still get no success .

I found this link but the results is not what I need :https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener

I have also been helped before but the example was too specific and I cannot do the same things because the documents is too long this is why I am looking for a way to make it generic: [Flatten json documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756308/flatten-json-documents-in-java)

I need to transform "any" json documents like in the example below :

Here is an example of my documents

Documents recieved:

```
{ 
  "took": 7, 
  "timed_out": false, 
  "_shards": { 
    "total": 5, 
    "successful": 5, 
    "failed": 0 
  }, 
  "hits": { 
    "total": 10, 
    "max_score": 0, 
    "hits": [] 
  }, 
  "aggregations": { 
    "groupe": { 
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
      "buckets": [ 
        { 
          "key": "a", 
          "doc_count": 1, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493769600000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 1 
                } 
              }, 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493776800000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 3 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        }, 
        { 
          "key": "b", 
          "doc_count": 4, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493769600000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 4 
                } 
              }, 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T01:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493773200000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 3 
                } 
              } 

            ] 
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Document Transformed:

```
{ 
  "took": 7, 
  "timed_out": false, 
  "_shards": { 
    "total": 5, 
    "successful": 5, 
    "failed": 0 
  }, 
  "hits": { 
    "total": 10, 
    "max_score": 0, 
    "hits": [] 
  }, 
  "aggregations": { 
    "groupe": { 
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
      "buckets": [ 
        { 
          "key": "a", 
          "doc_count": 1, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T00:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493769600000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 1 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        }, 
        { 
          "key": "a", 
          "doc_count": 1, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T02:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493776800000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 3 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        }, 
        { 
          "key": "b", 
          "doc_count": 1, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T02:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493776800000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 4 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        }, 

 "key": "b", 
          "doc_count": 1, 
          "date": { 
            "buckets": [ 
              { 
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-03T02:00:00.000Z", 
                "key": 1493776800000, 
                "doc_count": 1, 
                "value": { 
                  "value": 4 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        } 


      ] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of your yesterday question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756308/flatten-json-documents-in-java

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv  no really because the previous one was an example , this time I want to it for any json documents

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv If you look at the previous example you will see that the answer is specifique for example documents, but here we cannot do the same things because the documents is too long

Comment: What JSON libraries are allowed to use in your project? + Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Any json is allowed, at the moment I am using Json.org , simple json and I using  java 8